# Какие бывают квалификаторы андроид ресурсов

Tags: android, android-studio

Хотелось бы получить список всех существующих в андроид квалификаторов. Где можно их найти? Гугл мне дает очень разрозненные результаты. Я считаю должна существовать документация, где описывается что квалификатор `land` это для альбомной ориентации, квалификатор `v11` означает версию sdk, так же существую некие квалификаторы `sw` позволяющие прописать самому диапазон ширины экрана.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В [официальной документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) представлены все возможные каталоги и наименования квалификаторов ресурсов

Comment: Спасибо, может гугл мне и выдавал этот результат, но перейти на эту страницу я не  мог. РКН  заблокировал. пришлось через Tor открывать.